# bootstrap 5 resizing images in table on bigger screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 and a table (with `<table>` not `<div>` yes!) to display a bunch of images that also work as buttons. I'd like them to grow when I make the browser window wider. I also need all the Buttons with the embedded images to be aligned vertically. Max is 10 per row.
The table stretches horizontally over the window, but is in a container that adds some padding.

What I tried:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover caption-top">
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-2">store</td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">   
                <button class="imgButton"
                        style="background-image: url( '...' ); border: 2px solid red; transform: rotate(180deg);">
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">   
                <button class="imgButton" 
                        style="background-image: url( '...' ); border: 2px solid red; transform: rotate(180deg);">
                </button>   
            </td>            
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The imag urls are filled according to database values, some with `rotate(180deg)`, some without.

The CSS classes in place are:

```
.container-fluid.LRpadding {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.imgButton {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 64px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

Right now, the settings with pixels are supposed to be the minimal value. I tried setting the `.width` in `.imgButton` to `100%` and define a `min-width: 64px;` but that did not result in the desired output (images where slightly stretched horizontally also).

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate my situation:

https://jsfiddle.net/bs8xe2pv/2/

Comment: I do not understand how the images were stretched given you are using cover. Could you put up a working snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. And is using table essential?

Comment: I added a fiddle and I really like the table approach :)

Comment: I your fiddle lacking bootstrap - or something to give the cells a width?

Comment: I think I don't really get what you mean? There is bootstrap js, css and tags in the html (`<td class="col-sm-2">store 1</td>` for example)?

Comment: My mistake, I thought since the items were so narrow the library wasn't loaded, but I see it is linked to.

Comment: And would you have an idea on how to fit them to the cell size?